# How do I set a workbook-wide default format with Excel::Writer::XLSX?

Tags: perl, xlsx

Is it possible to change or declare a default font with [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX)?
I can set it for charts and cells every time I create or add them. But I think there should be a more simple way.

Comment: What module do you use? I can't find one named "xlswriter" on CPAN.

Comment: I am using [this](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Chart.pm) one.

Comment: I found a way and updated the answer.

Comment: @simbabque Thank you for your answer. I guessed it.My only problem was can't set chart series name's font. I read [document](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Chart.pm) many times but it seems there is no method for set font for series name.

Comment: There might not be. You can ask a new question for that and tag it appropriately. We now know that the author frequents SO, so he will probably answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Maybe.**

**Disclaimer:** the author of Excel::Writer::XLSX explains this is not a good idea and is not guaranteed to work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917767/how-do-i-set-a-workbook-wide-default-format-with-excelwriterxlsx/37918617?noredirect=1#comment63293812_37918617) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917767/how-do-i-set-a-workbook-wide-default-format-with-excelwriterxlsx/37918617?noredirect=1#comment63295522_37918617).

You can set the property `xf_index` to `0` when creating a Format object. That will set that Format as the default one.

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'filename.xlsx' );

# set the default format
$workbook->add_format(xf_index => 0, font => 'Comic Sans MS' ); # I'm on Linux

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->write( 0, 0, 'Hi Excel!' );      # will be in Comic Sans

my $format = $workbook->add_format(font => 'Arial' );
$worksheet->write( 1, 1, 'In Arial!', $format );
```

This is not described in the docs, but [reading the code](https://metacpan.org/source/JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.95/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Workbook.pm#L139) explains it.

It works even if you add more formats later. You do not need to keep the Format object of that initial call. It will be used throughout the workbook (probably also on different sheets, but I didn't test that).

I suggest explaining what you're doing in a code comment because it's really not very obvious.

After a bit of additional research I found it explained in [the PDF document *OpenOffice.org's Documentation of the Microsoft Excel File Format*](http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf),  in chapter 4.6.2 at the bottom of page 89 (emphasis mine).

> The default cell format
>   is always present in an Excel file, described by the XF record with the fixed index 15 (0-based). **By default, it uses the
>   worksheet/workbook default cell style, described by the very first XF record (index 0).**

So now we also know why it's `xf_index => 0`.

---

**Old answer with general advice:**

In general that's not supported. You need to work with formats. [The docs say](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#Working-with-formats) that there is a default format with Calibri in size 11.

> The default format is Calibri 11 with all other properties off.

You need to create a format object for a specific combination of formatting, font family, font size and so on and then you can reuse that throughout the document in each cell or chart. If one of the options differs in a specific cell, you need to make an additional Format object for that.

```
my $default_format = $workbook->add_format( font => 'Comic Sans' );

# ...

$worksheet->write( 'A1', 'Cell A1', $default_format );

# later ...

$worksheet->write( 'Z3', 'Cell Z3', $default_format );
```

If you need a lot of different formatting, but always want to use the same font, it might be useful to set the font string as a format hash and use that.

```
my %default_formatting = ( font => 'Comic Sans' );
my $bold_format = $workbook->add_format( %default_formatting, bold => 1 );
```

Maybe even make a sub that helps to create the Format objects and already knows about the default font.

```
sub create_format {
    my ($workbook, %formats) = @_;
    return $workbook->add_format( font => 'Comic Sans', %formats );
}

# somewhere
my $bold_format = create_format( $workbook, bold => 1 );
$worksheet->write( 'A1', 'Cell A1', $bold_format );
```

That would also allow *throw-away* formats like this:

```
$worksheet->write( 'D1', 'Weird stuff', create_format( 
    $workbook, 
    bold      => 1,
    strikeout => 1, 
    shadow    => 1,
    bg_color  => 'pink',
));
```

Comment: *Yes, but it's hidden. You can set the property xf_index to 0 when creating a Format object.* This is not guaranteed to work now or at anytime in the future. The only valid way to set the default format in Excel 2007+ is to update the theme.xml file and that isn't currently supported in Excel::Writer::XLSX.

Comment: @jmcnamara thank you for clarifying. But wouldn't that also apply to your code in the constructor where I found it?

Comment: The constructor sets the default format to match the default format in the default theme file. Your workaround may work in some cases but not all.

Comment: @jmcnamara I see. I don't even have an Excel to test with. I tried with Libre Office 5 and only with one case. But it looked like it worked. Is the old part of my answer valid in your opinion?

Comment: See my edit. I think it's clear now that it's maybe not a good idea to do this.

Comment: The old part of the answer still looks valid.

Comment: Thanks for answers. So I can set x, y axis fonts and title's font for Charts. But I can't set it for series names. I'm testing it on MS EXCEL 2010/2016.